# Establishing a public folder as my html website folder

Tags: google-drive-api

How do I establish a public folder as my html website folder?  I've read about the webViewLink, but I can't find out how to find that name/string without programming!

Thanks,

Christopher Anderson

Answer (score 0):

Check this recording of the Google Developers Live introductory session about Google Website Hosting for instructions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwyZqyGEPNk#!